# Callback function not getting called

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the code:

```
$scope.$watch($scope.getWidth, $scope.adjustSidebar);

    $scope.adjustSidebar = function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue >= mobileView) {
            if (angular.isDefined($cookieStore.get('sidebarToggle'))) {
                $scope.sidebarToggle = $cookieStore.get('sidebarToggle');
            } else {
                $scope.sidebarToggle = true;
            }
        } else {
            $scope.sidebarToggle = false;
        }
    };
```

If I insert the definition of $scope.adjustSidebar in as $watch's second argument, the code works fine. As soon as I try to extract it like this, the code breaks (i.e. $scope.adjustSidebar does not get executed on event fire). Why is this? What is the difference if I store the function in a variable and use the variable as the argument or use the actual definition as the argument? T

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe define the function before assigning it as call back.

Comment: Javascript ain't no TARDIS after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moved the callback to after the function call.

```
$scope.adjustSidebar = function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue >= mobileView) {
            if (angular.isDefined($cookieStore.get('sidebarToggle'))) {
                $scope.sidebarToggle = $cookieStore.get('sidebarToggle');
            } else {
                $scope.sidebarToggle = true;
            }
        } else {
            $scope.sidebarToggle = false;
        }
    };

    $scope.$watch($scope.getWidth, $scope.adjustSidebar);
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon. Please add some text to explain what you have done and why. And typically when there is already a comment explaining exactly the problem, at least mention it when you copy the solution